# center div horizontally in IE8

Tags: css, layout, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

On [this page](http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/), the main content is nested under `<div id="container">`. I've tried to center the content using:

```
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 960px;
}
```

It works fine in Firefox, but not in IE8 or IE9. Is there a way to center the content in all modern browsers?

Comment: site appears to be down.

Comment: @AndresIlich should be available now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you remove the `display: table` from your #stickyWrap element. Is there a reason you need that? It didn't seem to change anything else.

Comment: are you sure about that? I had a look in Firebug and it seems like `#stickWrap` has `display: block`

Comment: Yup, in the IE developer toolbar, it is definitey getting a display: table applied. If you don't want that, just set a display: block and it should be fixed for all. I do see that you correct about Firebug, these sorts of situations are why CSS resets are a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you alternate the document mode under the Developer Tools in IE8 you can see that your site works just fine using IE8 standards mode, so try to force that mode using the following meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8">
```

The other option would be to restructure your HTML to expose your `#container` outside of your `#stickyWrap` container, but that would take a bit of work.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue with Royal Slider buttons on a Wordpress theme and `display: table` worked like a charm.